# Showing rows 0 - 0 (1 total, Query took 0.0008 seconds.) in phpmyadmin SELECT WHERE 1

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have inserted a row in a phpmyadmin table but when i run any of following commands it returns:

Showing rows 0 - 0 (1 total, Query took 0.0008 seconds.)

```
SELECT * FROM library_info WHERE 1

SELECT * FROM library_info

SELECT * FROM library_info WHERE 1

SELECT * FROM library_info
```

[HOW THE DATA IS STORED IN THE TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bq9E0.jpg)

I need to use the same in my **login page** of php code for php page is

```
<?php
require('connect.inc.php');
// User is not logged in.
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['cmdlogin'])) {
    $u     = strip_tags($_POST['username']);
    $p     = strip_tags($_POST['password']);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM user_details WHERE USERNAME = '$u' AND PASSWORD = '$p'";
    echo $query;

    $result = mysql_query($query, $conn);
    if ($result) {
        echo "Valid";
    } else {
        echo "Invalid";
    } 
} else {
    echo "2";
    include 'index.php';
}
?>
```

Result:
`SELECT * FROM user_details WHERE USERNAME = 'Admin' and PASSWORD = 'JainLibrary'` Invalid

Comment: why `WHERE 1`? Is there a reason?

Comment: No there is no reason as I click on sql tab and click on select * it automatically added this where 1

Answer (score 4):

The row-counter is zero-based, so you get the 0-th row that is exactly the one you inserted.

Comment: What is this row counter  and how to change I need to use this information in my php page this same happens for my login

Comment: The problem if often outside he screen... The output of phpmyadmin is cluttered with a lot of information about the query and the sngle row also has a lot of action-links. So (especially if the table has very few columns) it's very easy to overlook the result. But it's there (as this answer correctly pointed me to..)

Answer (score 0):

Yeh i come to know the solution to my problems

Actually there was no issue with my phpMyAdmin Sql Query result.

row-counter is the index of the rows that results and it always starts from 0 and the table had only one row that's why it was showing Showing rows 0 - 0 (1 total, Query took 0.0008 seconds.).

**Secondly** my php code was of some issue

In some commands i used **"mysql_query"** or in others it was mysqli_query

i changed this line from

**mysql_query($query,$conn);**

to

**mysql_query($conn,$query);**

It worked fine 100%
Comment below if you need further assistance